# Creating "Next" and "Previous" buttons to navigate through an array using index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to implement  "Next" and "Previous" button to help me navigate through items in an array.

I am using the index of items in the array to get the next or the previous item.

Example:

```
  arrA =  [{_id:1,name:"T-Rex"},{_id:3,name:"Predator X"},{_id:4 ,name:"Velociraptor"},{_id: 6, name:"Triceratops"}]
```

The the id of the current object is represent by

```
var selectedID = _id
```

Next and Previous functions

```
  next(){
      var idx = arrA.map(x => x._id).indexOf(selectedID);

      if (idx === arrA.length - 1){
       //return first item
          var next_name = arrA[0].name;
      } else {
        var next_name = arrA[idx + 1].name
  }


  previous(){
      var idx = arrA.map(x => x._id).indexOf(selectedID);

        if (idx === arrA[0]){
         // return  last item
            var prev_name = arrA[arrA.length -1].name;
        } else{
          var prev_name = arrA[idx -1].name
  }

}
```

The expected outcome is that when I click either of the buttons, it should take me to the immediate next or previous item, but the actual outcome is that it loops through the array non-stop.

Comment: How do you call next() and previous() ?

Answer (score 2):

Everything becomes much simpler when modulo (%) is used. It allows you to advance (forwards or backwards) in a list without worrying if you come at the beginning or end.

```js
const arr =  [{_id:1,name:"T-Rex"},{_id:3,name:"Predator X"},{_id:4 ,name:"Velociraptor"},{_id: 6, name:"Triceratops"}]

let currentIndex = 0;
let currentId = arr[0]._id;

// initial log
log();

function next(){
  move();
}

function previous(){
  move(false);
}

function move(advance = true){
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + (advance ? 1 : -1) + arr.length) % arr.length;
  currentId = arr[currentIndex]._id;
  log();
}

function log(){
  console.log("Index: " + currentIndex, "Id: " + currentId);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="previous();">Previous</button>
<button onclick="next();">Next</button>
```

Comment: this is working out fine, but when i click on either of the buttons it gets stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: @SteveGaita could you clarify what you mean by infinite loop? Are you referring to when you reach the end of the list that you start back at the start?

Comment: by infinite loop, i mean instead of it moving to the next or previous item with a click on either of the buttons, it moves loops through all the items with just one click, then repeats the whole process again without stopping.

Comment: @SteveGaita with my current setup that's not possible. Are you calling the `next` and `previous` multiple times in a row with a loop?

Comment: not really. Let me try and share my actual code implementation